# Including javascript function, does not work on android

Tags: javascript, android, html

i'm trying to solve a strange problem. I have realized a personnalized project for 2 weeks ago creating personnalized widget and event on them and as a result i want to deploy it on my android device.
For example, this link : http://jsfiddle.net/fc8hL/ show you a checkBox example :

--> first *div* is a container which can include many checkboxes

--> second *div* is a checkbox container

--> three *img* in the previous div are differents images which appear according to mouse/touch event on the checkbox.

--> the js function "check(e)" allows me to treat these 3 images and the event.

THIS FUNCTION WORKS PERFECTLY on both my local computer and my android device! i have realized some others functions in order to put in the HTML buttons, radio and comboBox.

Some events are attributed to this widgets. 
Problem is : the final html file is huge : indeed, there is one function per img and i would like to optimize it creating javascript file. That is easy, i just put

`<script "checkBox.js"> ***My existing function that works !***
</script>`

And when i open my html file... surprise ! that works on my local computer, but not on my android device... Are you seeing an issue for this problem ?

Comment: Debug it: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thx for your answer, i'm a beginner in android technology, i will try it :)

Comment: NITPICK: do not use `javascript:` in event attributes.

Comment: i cleared them, but there is the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys,

i have debugged my program thanks to epascarello link, and i found my problem.

On my remote computer, an error is showing :

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"**

All my files are on a server and i didn't change reading options on them, that's why i couldn't access to all javascripts functions included in these files. Bad mistake...

Thanks a lot for your help :)